# Is it okay to attach methods to singleton arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any reason why attaching methods to an individual instance of
Array might be inadvisable?

Everyone on my team seems to agree that this is fine:

```
function communicate() {
  console.log(this.sound);
}

var maru     = {name: 'Maru',     sound: 'prrrrrr'};
var garfield = {name: 'Garfield', sound: 'Anyone up for lasagna?'};
maru.talk = garfield.talk = communicate;
```

There's always the option of making a formal constructor, but
if you only need one cat, it's nice that you don't have to bother.

This is a bit more controversial on my team:

```
function socialize() {
  this.forEach(function(creature) {
    creature.talk();
  });
}

var cats = [garfield, maru];
cats.meowfest = socialize;

cats.meowfest();
//=> prrrrrr
//=> Anyone up for lasagna?
```

Other developers on my team insist we must subclass Array rather than
adding methods on-the-fly. To me, it seems like the same fundamental
principle as in the first example. There's always the option of making a
formal constructor, but if you only need one cats array, it's nice that
you don't have to bother. Am I wrong?

So far, I've only heard two arguments against it:

1. It's monkey patching and monkey patching is dangerous.

This isn't monkey patching. I actually agree monkey patching is usually
a bad practice, but in this case, you're not affecting the prototype at
all. You modified an instance, not the prototype. Here's a proof:

```
var arr1 = [];
arr1.foo = function() {return 'bar'};
arr1.foo(); // 'bar'

var arr2 = [];
arr2.foo(); // undefined is not a function
```

Adding the method to `arr1` was perfectly safe and did not affect `arr2`
at all.

2. It breaks for-in.

You don't use for-in on arrays anyway, for-in is for objects
and returns keys. For arrays, it would just return integers 0 to the
length. Instead, you just use forEach, which works fine.

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
letters.foo = function() {return 'bar'};
for (key in letters) {
  console.log(key);
}
//=> '0'
//=> '1'
//=> '2'
//=> 'foo'

letters.forEach(function(letter) {
  console.log(letter);
});
//=> 'a'
//=> 'b'
//=> 'c'
```

The output of for-in wasn't particularly useful before we added the
method. I actually like that it logs the method name though, this to me
seems like good intuitive behavior. Moreover, the output for forEach was
unaffected, which is exactly what I wanted.

So how does the community feel about adding methods to an array
on-the-fly? Are we pro or anti?

Comment: The main reason not to use *for..in* with arrays is that you don't know what order the properties will be returned in. There is no difference between adding properties to an array or *Array.prototype* in that regard, a *hasOwnProperty* test should usually be used anyway in most cases (but *Object.keys* more convenient now).

Comment: it's fine, arrays are objects, might as well use them. it's not like you need to map() or filter() those methods in the data part (num index), and alpha props don't even affect .length, so regular for loops still work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's completely okay. Arrays are objects, so you can add arbitrary properties to them.

It's true that it may break some code which iterates an array with a `for...in` loop. To avoid that, you can define your property as non-enumerable:

```js
Object.defineProperty(cats, 'meowfest', {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: socialize
});
```

Comment: I don't understand people who down vote and don't say why. :-/

Comment: @RobG Looking at the timeline, I think somebody didn't like the question and didn't like that I answered it.